# One hot encoding - encode multiple columns as one

Tags: python, pandas

I want to encode a dataframe that has multiple columns of the same "type", for example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["France", "Bupapest", "Sweden", "Paris"], ["Italy", "Frankfurt", "France", "Naples"]], columns=["Countries 1", "Cities 1", "Countries 2", "Cities 2"])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Countries 1   Cities 1 Countries 2 Cities 2
0      France   Bupapest      Sweden    Paris
1       Italy  Frankfurt      France   Naples
```

How do I encode this dataframe with one hot encoding by passing in column indices which should be considered as one? In this example, I would pass in [0, 2] and [1, 3] because Countries 1 and Countries 2 column has 3 different countries combined and therefore should have 3 categories, not 2 each and the same principle goes for the two countries columns.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 2):

I am using `wide_to_long` flatten the df , then using `factorize`+`unstack`

```
s=pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),stubnames=['Countries','Cities'],i='index',j='unstack',sep=' ').apply(lambda x : pd.factorize(x)[0]+1).unstack()

s.columns=s.columns.map('{0[0]} {0[1]}'.format)

s=s.reindex(columns=df.columns)
s
Out[1377]: 
       Countries 1  Cities 1  Countries 2  Cities 2
index                                              
0                1         1            3         3
1                2         2            1         4
```

Or get_dummies

```
s=pd.get_dummies(pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),stubnames=['Countries','Cities'],i='index',j='unstack',sep=' '))

s
Out[1392]: 
               Countries_France  Countries_Italy  Countries_Sweden  \
index unstack                                                        
0     1                       1                0                 0   
1     1                       0                1                 0   
0     2                       0                0                 1   
1     2                       1                0                 0   
               Cities_Bupapest  Cities_Frankfurt  Cities_Naples  Cities_Paris  
index unstack                                                                  
0     1                      1                 0              0             0  
1     1                      0                 1              0             0  
0     2                      0                 0              0             1  
1     2                      0                 0              1             0
```

Comment: One hot encoding means the output should be binarized

Comment: This is just label encoding, I need to feed it to a neural network. All categories should be weighted equally, but in this way Italy is considered "better" than France for example because it's a higher number. https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f

Comment: How do I convert it to a 2D array? When I call as_matrix() it gives me 4 rows, but there should only be 2 rows like in the original.

Comment: @Martin s.sum(level=1)

Comment: If I call as_matrix() on that it gives me 2 rows, but this can't be right: 
[[1 1 0 1 1 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0 1 1]]

Comment: @Martin sorry kindly change s.sum(level=0)

Comment: Well, I'm unsure of how to read it exactly, but I would think there should be 3 + 4 + 3 + 4 digits on each row.

Comment: Gives me the same format, just different numbers. Still not 14 columns, though: 
[[1 0 1 1 0 0 1]
 [1 1 0 0 1 1 0]]

Comment: Oh, I see. With s.sum it just takes the sum thereby squishing the matrix to have 2 rows instead of 4, but what it should be doing is rearranging the numbers from being a 4x7 matrix to 2x14

Comment: @Martin then we doing s.unstack()

Comment: Now it's the correct format, but the numbers are wrong, for example 011 would mean being multiple categories at once which is invalid: [[1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]]

Comment: @Martin if you can provide what you need , that would be helpful , also, did you check the column names after s.unstack()

Comment: Well, there are multiple valid outputs depending on the order of the columns. Although the categorial output you got translated to one hot encoding, which is the expected valid output is [[1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0] [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]]